# Inconsistency using a binding from a published var across different iOS versions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI screen that pre-populates custom text fields with existing values. I would like to prevent the user from entering more than 10 characters in one of the fields. I am using an `@Published` var in the `ViewModel`, and using the `projectedValue` to get a Binding for the value to pass along to the `CustomTextField`.

I am relatively new to SwiftUI, so I expect this is just a shortcoming of my understanding of either:

1. How @Published vars work WRT using their projectedValue binding
2. How @Binding works
3. When to use which Property Wrappers
4. Scenarios where a view might not be invalidated
5. A combination of all of the above

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(binding: $viewModel.firstName)
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var binding: String
    
    init(binding: Binding<String>) {
        _binding = binding
        print(binding)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        getBody()
    }
    
    private func getBody() -> some View {
        print("getting body")
        return TextField("", text: $binding)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstName: String {
        didSet {
            if firstName.count > 10 { firstName = oldValue }
        }
    }
    
    init(initialFirstNameValue: String) {
        firstName = initialFirstNameValue
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the included code works as I expect for iOS 16. However, on iOS 15 and iOS 17, the user is able to enter > 10 characters into the text field. Using the print statements, after the user enters > 10 characters, it looks like the `CustomTextField` is being initialized with the correct binding, but the view's body is never being fetched.

It's worth noting that I was actually able to solve this problem using `TextField.onChange`, but for educational purposes, I would like to understand where I went wrong with the above approach